# Mootools Class to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, mootools

I'm converting a mootools class to Jquery, but I'm with a problem at the moment.

I've the following code (mootools)

```
var ListaItens = new Class({

    ...

    ...

    initialize: function(element){
        ....

        this.btnAdd = this.tabela.getElement('.add_linha button');
        if(this.btnAdd){
            this.btnAdd.addEvent('click', this.addLinha.bindWithEvent(this));
            this.checkAdd();
        }

        ...
    },

    addLinha: function(){

    }   
});
```

Now in Jquery I've this

```
var ListaItens = function(element, maxLinhas){

    ...

    this.btnAdd = this.tabela.find('.add_linha button')[0];
    if(this.btnAdd){
        //$(this.btnAdd).proxy('click', this.addLinha);
        $(this.btnAdd).on("click", this.addLinha);
        this.checkAdd;
    }

    ...

    this.addLinha = function(){

    }
})
```

My problem is how to bind the addline function to btnAdd. My code isn't work because the element 'this' change. And I don't know how to convert the function bindWithEvent to jquery.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, jQuery does not provide a similar concept of classes as mootools does, so one thing you can do is to use the »classic JS approach« to create classes like so:

```
function ListaItens () {
    var that = this;

    this.tabela = $(…);
    this.btnAdd = this.tabela.find(…);

    if (this.btnAdd) {
        this.this.btnAdd.on('click', function (e) {
            that.addLinha();
        })
    }
}

ListaItens.prototype.addLinha = function () {

}

var instance = new ListaItens();
```

So, to answer your question: What you basically need to do is to keep a reference to the »original this«